# Extracting data with BeautifulSoup and output to CSV

Tags: python, csv

As mentioned in the previous questions, I am using Beautiful soup with python to retrieve weather data from a website.

Here's how the website looks like:

```
<channel>
<title>2 Hour Forecast</title>
<source>Meteorological Services Singapore</source>
<description>2 Hour Forecast</description>
<item>
<title>Nowcast Table</title>
<category>Singapore Weather Conditions</category>
<forecastIssue date="18-07-2016" time="03:30 PM"/>
<validTime>3.30 pm to 5.30 pm</validTime>
<weatherForecast>
<area forecast="TL" lat="1.37500000" lon="103.83900000" name="Ang Mo Kio"/>
<area forecast="SH" lat="1.32100000" lon="103.92400000" name="Bedok"/>
<area forecast="TL" lat="1.35077200" lon="103.83900000" name="Bishan"/>
<area forecast="CL" lat="1.30400000" lon="103.70100000" name="Boon Lay"/>
<area forecast="CL" lat="1.35300000" lon="103.75400000" name="Bukit Batok"/>
<area forecast="CL" lat="1.27700000" lon="103.81900000" name="Bukit Merah"/>` 
<channel>
```

I managed to retrieve the information I need using these codes :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

#getting the ValidTime

r = requests.get('http://www.nea.gov.sg/api/WebAPI/?   
dataset=2hr_nowcast&keyref=781CF461BB6606AD907750DFD1D07667C6E7C5141804F45D')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "xml")
time = soup.find('validTime').string
print "validTime: " + time

#getting the date

for currentdate in soup.find_all('item'):
    element = currentdate.find('forecastIssue')
    print "date: " + element['date']

#getting the time

for currentdate in soup.find_all('item'):
    element = currentdate.find('forecastIssue')
    print "time: " + element['time'] 

for area in soup.find('weatherForecast').find_all('area'):
    area_attrs_li = [area.attrs for area in soup.find('weatherForecast').find_all('area')]
    print area_attrs_li
```

Here are my results :

```
{'lat': u'1.34039000', 'lon': u'103.70500000', 'name': u'Jurong West',   
'forecast': u'LR'}, {'lat': u'1.31200000', 'lon': u'103.86200000', 'name':  
 u'Kallang', 'forecast': u'LR'},
```

1. How do I remove u' from the result? I tried using the method I found while googling but it doesn't seem to work

I'm not strong in Python and have been stuck at this for quite a while.

**EDIT** : I tried doing this :

```
f = open("C:\\scripts\\nea.csv" , 'wt')

try:
 for area in area_attrs_li:
 writer = csv.writer(f)
 writer.writerow( (time, element['date'], element['time'], area_attrs_li))

finally:
  f.close()

print open("C:/scripts/nea.csv", 'rt').read()
```

It worked however, I would like to split the area apart as the records are duplicates in the CSV :

[image: records in the CSV]

Thank you.

Comment: Your "website" looks like plain XML

Comment: Yes, i believe its just a plain XML

Comment: For question #2, you shouldn't need to remove the u. It stands for unicode, and that's how python will represent the string internally, not when you write to a file. Which, you should describe the problem you're having doing

Comment: I went around googling but I cant seem to run the codes without errors. I forgot what errors were they as I did that a few days back :/

Comment: Well, it'll be hard to help without knowing what your errors are. Also, you've shown JSON or python dictionary output. However, your code doesn't print that?

Comment: Oh, that was when I wanted to output as a JSON file before I found out that CSV is the most suitable file type when I want to insert data into the DB

Comment: May I know how do I start coding to output as a csv?

Comment: Open a file object? Use the write method and join a list of data with some commas?

Comment: I've edited my question!

Comment: You're quoting your variables... And you unquote when you try to access a list element

Comment: Hi! It works, but may I ask how do I code to print the area into different rows instead of putting everything into a row

Comment: I believe you'll need to manually write a new line character. `\n`

Comment: Or you should be using `wb` to write binary and `rb` to read binary.

Comment: I tried to add it under print area_attrs_li+"\n" and I got this error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neaweather.py", line 25, in <module>
    print area_attrs_li+"\n"
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: common mistake... `str(value) + '\n'`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want on newlines... You shouldn't be adding a new line to a list. I think you want to loop over the list and write new rows, no?

Comment: yes, i would like the area to be written on different rows in the csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 1 -Topic:

You're missing escape characters:

```
C:\scripts>python neaweather.py
File "neaweather.py", line 30
writer.writerow( ('time', 'element['date']', 'element['time']', 'area_attrs_li') )

writer.writerow( ('time', 'element[\'date\']', 'element[\'time\']', 'area_attrs_li') 
                                   ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

EDIT 2:

if you want to insert values:

```
writer.writerow( (time, element['date'], element['time'], area_attrs_li) )
```

EDIT 3:

to split the result to different lines:

```
for area in area_attrs_li:
    writer.writerow( (time, element['date'], element['time'], area)
```

EDIT 4:
The splitting is not correct at all, but it shall give a better understanding of how to parse and split data to change it for your needs.
[image]
to split the area element again as you show in your image, you can parse it

```
for area in area_attrs_li:
    # cut off the characters you don't need
    area = area.replace('[','')
    area = area.replace(']','')
    area = area.replace('{','')
    area = area.replace('}','')

    # remove other characters
    area = area.replace("u'","\"").replace("'","\"")

    # split the string into a list
    areaList = area.split(",")

    # create your own csv-seperator
    ownRowElement = ';'.join(areaList)

    writer.writerow( (time, element['date'], element['time'], ownRowElement)
```

Offtopic:
This works for me:

```
import csv
import json

x="""[ 
    {'lat': u'1.34039000', 'lon': u'103.70500000', 'name': u'Jurong West','forecast': u'LR'}
]"""

jsontxt = json.loads(x.replace("u'","\"").replace("'","\""))

f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "w+"))

# Write CSV Header, If you dont need that, remove this line
f.writerow(['lat', 'lon', 'name', 'forecast'])

for jsontext in jsontxt:
    f.writerow([jsontext["lat"], 
                jsontext["lon"], 
                jsontext["name"], 
                jsontext["forecast"],
                ])
```

Comment: The question is about XML, not JSON.

Comment: Hi, it works by splitting it into different columns :) How do I edit your codes if I would like it to run the website? :)

Comment: Agreed. The question has a python dictionary, not JSON

Comment: oh right. I'am sorry. Some code was edited. You are missing escape character: writer.writerow( ('time', 'element[\'date\']', 'element[\'time\']', 'area_attrs_li') )

Comment: Hi, i changed the writerow according to what you've commented, and there is nothing in the csv except the headers 'time', 'element[\'date\']', 'element[\'time\']', 'area_attrs_li' :O

Comment: because you write the strings itself -> 'time' vs the variable time with its value . try to write it without ' and add a for loop to insert values

Comment: how should the loop be? Sorry im not very strong in python

Comment: Since area_attrs_li has all the elements you need to split to different lines you need to loop over this list: for area in area_attrs_li: writer.writerow( (time, element['date'], element['time'], area))

Comment: Ohhh, but is there any way to split up only the areas into different rows?

Comment: Do you mean this: for area in area_attrs_li: writer.writerow( (area)) ?